# Какой командой скопировать (извлечь) текст в буфер обмена в Google Colab?

Tags: python, clipboard, google-colaboratory

Функция

```
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

не работает, хотя установка и импорт библиотеки происходят удачно, она выдает:

```
PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error
```

но по указанному адресу нет решения данной проблемы, явно нужно использовать другой механизм, но какой?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Команда должна поместить строку в буфер обмена (то же что делает """pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')"""), только работать в Google Colab

Comment: Интересно, как вы это себе представляете? Программа в Colab исполняется в облаке, а буфер обмена на вашем компе.

Comment: А почему именно буфер обмена... даже если бы и получилось, зачем? Может стоит рассмотреть передачу через обычный файл...